# Laravel 5.8 initiate DB::beginTransaction() on a different database per user

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have an app where the user owns their own DB. I am creating a record save which includes a relationship (so two tables updated) and I want to wrap the execution with `DB::transaction()`. The only issue is the DB name must change user by user.

The `$user->db_name` contains the data expected and it works well with other selection queries.

If I do this it fails with `Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null`

```php
DB::disconnect(config('database.default'));
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $user->db_name);

DB::beginTransaction();

try {
.
.
    $data1->create();
    $data2->create();

    DB::commit();
 } catch (\Exception $e) {
     DB::rollback();
 }
```

If I do this and force a fail on the second create statement, it keeps the record in table from the first create.

```php
DB::beginTransaction();

try {

    DB::disconnect(config('database.default'));
    Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $user->db_name);

.
.
    $data1->create();
    $data2->create();

    DB::commit();
 } catch (\Exception $e) {
     DB::rollback();
 }
```

How do I achieve the DB change and transaction with rollback on failure against a user's db? Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to not create a separate database for each user? There might be a reason why this is not properly working in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Use `reconnect()`:

```php
DB::reconnect(config('database.default'));
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $user->db_name);

DB::beginTransaction();

try {
.
.
    $data1->create();
    $data2->create();

    DB::commit();
 } catch (\Exception $e) {
     DB::rollback();
 }
```